# Formulas for Integral Components

Tags: pcb, capacitor, capacitance, capacitive, parasitic-capacitance

### Formulas for Integral Components:

I am looking for "simple" approximative formulas for integral components. In particular for:

- A grounded interdigital capacitor (i.e. above a ground plane and with one set of fingers connected to ground), and
- a square pad on an infinite ground plane (to estimate SMT pad capacitance). *I believe that due to the method of images this is equivalent to a finite parallel plate capacitor with twice the separation but I am not 100% sure.*

### Sanity-Check Request:

Maybe somebody is also able to sanity-check the following reasoning.

In the absence of a formula for a grounded interdigital capacitor, would the following provide a reasonable estimate:

1. Calculate the capacitance between the two sets of fingers (with the available formulas)
2. Add the capacitance of a microstrip of equivalent length to the total length for microstrip contained in one set of fingers

Example using the formula provided [here](http://books.google.de/books?id=91UsWxk1CYkC&pg=PA230&lpg=PA230):

- er = 4.2
- t =  70 µm (copper thickness)
- h = 1.6 mm
- W' = 9.9 mm
- l = 8.4 mm
- W=S=l'=s' = 0.3 mm

A1 = 3.63*10^-3 pF/mm, 
A2 = 8.27*10^-3 pF/mm,
N = W'/(W+S)+1 = 17

$$ C_{interdigital} = 2.58 pF $$

Length of microstrip in one set of fingers (the one with 9 fingers):

$$ L_{microstrip} = 9.9 mm + 9\times(8.4+0.3) mm = 88.2 mm $$

$$ C_{microstrip} = 88.2 mm \times 0.0431 pF/mm = 3.80 pF $$

It follows that the interdigital capacitor presents an approximate capacitance to ground of about:

$$ C_{total} = C_{interdigital} + C_{microstrip} = 6 pF $$

Does this calculation make any sense at all?

Comment: Can you copy the diagram here.

Comment: @geometrikal That would violate the publisher's copyright: Google has special permission to display parts of the books it shows in Google Books. The link I included leads however directly to the diagram so I think the burden on the reader is not too great.

Comment: @Arik The link doesn't work for me.  In the USA the courts would almost certainly find that clipping that diagram and using it here is [fair use](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use#Fair_use_under_United_States_law).  This site is hosted in USA.